# Android studio 3.0 - Cant run app

Tags: android, android-studio

So far i only worked on the computer from my job and today im trying to setup my project on my home computer but no luck so far.

I guess it has to with gradle configurations or android studio 3.0 but the settings are the same for both computers, i get no errors but cant click the run button, adding run configuration doesnt work either.

**My gradle:**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'http://github.com/wada811/Android-Material-Design-Colors/raw/master/repository/' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help but my gradle.build is this for my apps. Maybe try using mine? Or an upgrade on your android studio, I know the earlier ones have bugs. The newer versions always seem to run more smoothly

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```